# Is there a way to create a postmeta field in database when new post is made, but have no meta input on admin side?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've taken over a site someone else built with a VERY poorly coded theme and VERY poorly coded plugins.   I just need a really quick temporary fix for an issue.

The site has a "projects" page, which is set up as a custom post type, and each project has a project type and list of services, both of which are set up as taxonomies/terms.

The problem is all of the old projects have fields in the `postmeta` table for `project_type` and `services`

However, neither the theme nor the CMB2 plugin create this field when a new project is made. If I manually create the fields in the database I can then change the information from the WP-admin, but then I would have to add them manually each time a new project is made.

If I add a metabox either manually or through the CMB2 plugin, it creates a second field for the same item in the admin back end, so that won't work.

Is there any way to just create these empty database fields in the postmeta table each time a new post is made?

P.S. I know there must just be an error somewhere in the theme or plugins but I don't have time to hunt through someone elses poorly formatted, uncommented code when all I need is a temporary fix until I can rebuild the site.